# How can I pass domain_hint parameter in Msal.UserAgentApplication method

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

I want to pass the domain hint as a parameter in MSAL.UserAgentApplication constructor which should be able to redirect Azure Login based on the Claim Provider domain.

`var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' });`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to supply a domain hint for single sign-on using MSAL.NET on a Blazor WebAssembly Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605653/is-there-a-way-to-supply-a-domain-hint-for-single-sign-on-using-msal-net-on-a-bl)

Answer (score 3):

I had found the solution. We can pass domain hint by using below code

```
var extraParameters = "domain_hint=facebook";
clientApplication.loginRedirect(applicationConfig.b2cScopes, extraParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

For MSAL 1.0, the `loginRedirect()` parameters have changed.  You now need to do this:

```
const loginConfig = {
    scopes: appConfig.b2cScopes,
    extraQueryParameters: { domain_hint: 'facebook' }
}

clientApplication.loginRedirect(loginConfig);
```

Comment: Can we also pass the login hint values
.. like while clicking on SignUp I want to pass emailaddress so that I don't need to fill it again in Microsoft login page...

Comment: I had to use  `{ domainHint: 'mydomain.com' }` and not domain_hint per https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#redirectrequest .  It is confusing to me when to use which one.