# Is there a way to supply a domain hint for single sign-on using MSAL.NET on a Blazor WebAssembly Client?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly

Is there any way to supply a domain hint (or otherwise avoid the need for the "pick an account" prompt) when using **MSAL.NET** in a Blazor WebAssembly application on the **client** side? I thought maybe it would be a setting or option passed in to builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication, but I don't see it.

[I figured it out for the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604911/is-there-a-way-to-supply-a-domain-hint-for-single-sign-on-using-msal-net), but not the client yet.  Without being able to set this, I get redundant "pick an account" prompts from microsoftonline.com when trying to authenticate.

I currently have, in Program.cs on the client:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(myScope);
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work in .NET 7+ out of [following up to this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45468).  The Blazor code that redirects to login should be something like this.

```cs
private void NavigateToLogin()
{

      InteractiveRequestOptions requestOptions = new()
      {
          Interaction = InteractionType.SignIn,
          ReturnUrl =  Navigation.Uri
      };

      requestOptions.TryAddAdditionalParameter("domainHint", "mydomain.com");
      Navigation.NavigateToLogin(Options.Get(DefaultOptionName).AuthenticationPaths.LogInPath, requestOptions);
}
```

Note it is `domainHint` and not `domain_hint`.

Comment: Only works to .NET 7.0. Is there some way to do the same thing in 6.0?

Answer (score 5):

Sending the domain_hint with Blazor web assembly is not supported currently. I have opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/13297) to track this further.

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue, but it looks like the issue was closed and the PR linked to the closure didn't help me understand the current state. Is there an update to this or link to a new open issue?

Comment: @MattSanders I'm just as confused about this. Being searching for the last few hours and there does not seem to be anything new about this issue. As i'm reading this, they are not going to fix this.

Comment: It seems this way.  New issue added: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45468 - If you can go there and add your comments, especially expressing your need or business case, that will help prioritize it.